# Importing Large File txt Postgres

Tags: postgresql, import

I am trying to import txt file using copy, but it won't work and getting error code

```
ERROR:  program "cmd /c "type d:/this/all.txt"" failed
DETAIL:  child process exited with exit code 1
SQL state: 38000
```

And try any code that I found but can't find answer, this my code

```
copy tablename (a, b, c, d) from program 'cmd /c "type d:/this/all.txt"' with ( format text, delimiter '|' );
```

Comment: Why use `cmd /c type`? Why not use `copy tablename (..:) from 'd:/this/all.txt'` directly?

Comment: because any sources that I've seen they suggest using cmd

Comment: Look in the database servers log file to see why CMD failed.  Or don't use it in the first place, it looks fragile and useless.